# How to write .csv file to my table in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: csv, progress-4gl, openedge

I have CSV file with as follows :

```
ABC,1,Service completion date/time  actual
ABC,2,Delivery date/time  requested
ABC,3,Invoice date/time
ABC,4,Order date/time
ABC,5,Saleable stock demand cover period  expected
ABC,6,Moved from location date
```

How can I write it to a table name T with fields f1 f2 and f3? There is a line break before each ABC

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with INPUT and IMPORT.

If each row in the file is one record this is one way:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE t NO-UNDO
    FIELD f1 AS CHARACTER
    FIELD f2 AS CHARACTER
    FIELD f3 AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE STREAM strImport.
DEFINE VARIABLE cCsvFile AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

cCsvFile = "c:\temp\myfile.csv".

INPUT STREAM strImport FROM VALUE(cCsvFile).
REPEAT :
    CREATE t.
    /* Default separator is space so use , instead */
    IMPORT STREAM strImport DELIMITER "," t.

END.
INPUT CLOSE.


FOR EACH t:
    DISPLAY t.
END.
```

Comment: I wonder if that'll work since his CSV strings are missing the quotes.

Comment: @TimKuehn I've tested it with OE11.6 in Windows 7 and it works. (Online help states: ... You must enclose all character fields in quotes ("") if they contain any delimiter characters.... So without delimiter characters quote free strings seems OK (but perhaps very unpractical if you're using a normal comma as delimiter as it's quite common in texts).